# Trouble reading NCES IPEDS csv file with pandas

Tags: pandas, csv, unicode

ran into a trouble downloading and reading csv files provided by US Department of Education National Center for Education Statistics. Below is code that should run for folks that might be interested in helping me troubleshoot.

```
import requests, zipfile, io

# First example shows that the code can work. Works fine on years 2005
# and earlier.
url = 'https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/data/HD2005_Data_Stata.zip'
r_zip_file_2005 = requests.get(url, stream=True)
z_zip_file_2005 = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r_zip_file_2005.content))
z_zip_file_2005.extractall('.')
csv_2005_df = pd.read_csv('hd2005_data_stata.csv')

# Second example shows that something changed in the CSV files after
# 2005 (or seems to have changed).
url = 'https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/data/HD2006_Data_Stata.zip'
r_zip_file_2006 = requests.get(url, stream=True)
z_zip_file_2006 = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r_zip_file_2006.content))
z_zip_file_2006.extractall('.')
csv_2006_df = pd.read_csv('hd2006_data_stata.csv')
```

For 2006 Python raises:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 18: invalid start byte
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-b26a150e37ee> in <module>()
----> 1 csv_2006_df = pd.read_csv('hd2006_data_stata.csv')
```

Any tips on how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Only took 7 months... Figured my answer. Wasn't rocket science.

```
csv_2006_df = pd.read_csv('hd2006_data_stata.csv', 
                          encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```